# Is there a lolcode compiler for x86 or x86_64?

Tags: compiler-construction, lolcode

On the [lolcode](http://www.lolcode.com) website I saw many references to various lolcode interpreters. But is there a lolcode compiler for the x86 or x86_64 architecture, that compiles directly to native machine code?

I have looked at several interpreter implementations, including [Lci](http://icanhaslolcode.org), lolcode.net (compiler to .NET), and lolcode interpreters in Python, Java and JavaScript. None of these do what I want.

Part of my rationale for asking is that if no such compiler exists, I may be interested in working on one, possibly by writing a LOLCODE -> C translator, and then leveraging a C compiler such as GCC to target native architectures.

Comment: Why the downvote? Lolcode may seem like a joke to you (whoever downvoted), but it is a programming language with nearly 20 implementations!

Comment: There is a compiler to .NET on the implementation list, but you are looking for a compiler to machine code, right? A lolcode interpreter in lolcode is missing too :)

Comment: I am aware of the compiler which targets the .NET. :)

Comment: The fact that lolcode is a joke, doesn't make it any less a programming language. On-topic, IMO.

Comment: @Patrick, the C interpreter for LOLCODE is pretty good.

Comment: @GoranJovic: that is exactly my point.

Comment: @DejanLekic: Can you show us what *you* have found out so far?

Comment: phresnel, I've found interpreters in all mainstream languages, compiler to .NET, but no compiler native code. I was thinking that perhaps the best would be to do a LOLCODE -> C translator, and then use a C compiler like GCC to target anything...

Comment: @phresnel: I would not ask this question on StackOverflow if a search engine gave me the answer... The second reason I ask this question is a research - if there are no compilers, I may decide to work on one.

Comment: @DejanLekic: Mention what you have tried. Or do you want us to make the same mistakes? It is not mockery, rather we want you to help us :)

Comment: The first (and the best) I tried is Lci ( http://www.icanhaslolcode.org/ ). I also tried the lolcode.net (.NET), lolcode interpreter in Python, Java and JavaScript.

Comment: Just as a suggestion if you eventually decide to write your own compiler: Try out LLVM, it makes writing compilers for new languages so easy - there's even a tutorial somewhere on the site on how to build a mini-compiler. Definitively sounds like fun!

Comment: http://lolcode.com/implementations/implementations That's your best resource. There's a 1.2 Java implementation that has a heck of a lot of functionality (and, being Java, would use x64 if your JVM is there). I actually used it for a heck of a lot of scripting and it was relatively elegant (and fun). Stupidly,  LOL -> OpenJDK (GNU) -> Native actually works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently there were at least two attempts of translating lolcode to LLVM bytecode

- https://github.com/meh/llvm-lol
- https://github.com/scooby/lolcode

Having LLVM bytecode you can easily translate it into optimised target architecture's assembly by using for example [llc](http://llvm.org/cmds/llc.html) and get native binaries out of it.

As a matter of fact, you can also [generate JavaScript](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten) using this approach.

Have fun.

Comment: CAN I HAS LOLCODE S.HIGHLIGHT ON SO?